# Access Container Files within an Azure WebApp for Containers

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-storage, azure-webapps

I have started a multi-container web app within azure.
Now I would like to access the files within the container, from the Kudu bash - for example, or some other tool.

The goal is to be able to copy and paste certain files within a folder before I map external (Azure) storage to this container.

My container does not offer SSH connection. I thought I would be able to access the files through the `kudu` bash. But I don't know where they reside.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to be able to copy and paste certain files within a folder before I map external (Azure) storage to this container.

- [Linux containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux&tabs=portal#link-storage-to-your-app) support files share & blobs if you are trying to mount the external storage to the container the directory where you are trying to mount should be empty.
- Windows containers support only Azure file shares and premium file share.

**Note** : Azure Storage in App Service Windows container is  **in preview**  and  **not supported**  for  **production scenarios**.

> My container does not offer SSH connection. I thought I would be able to access the files through the `kudu` bash. But I don't know where they reside.

- Based on the above statement, we understood that you are using windows containers.
- if you deploy your web app with Linux OS+ containerization then the kudu console supports SSH & bash
- if you deploy your web app with windows OS + containerization then you will have CMD/PowerShell in the kudu

In [windows containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-windows&tabs=portal#link-storage-to-your-app) It's always mounted on the `C:\` drive. for Linux containers, there is not default mount path.